# Hide div based on different domains

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two domains domainone.com and domaintwo.com both are aliases of one and another, however I'm wanting the logo of the site to change based on which URL is loaded.

The reason why is because it's a URL shortening script so there's no point me running multiple of the same scripts.

For example:

`domainone.com/b` should show `logoone.png` and `domaintwo.com/b` should show `logotwo.png`

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a switch statement or several if statements using `window.location.hostname`, which is the hostname of the current website (ie. domainone or domaintwo), and from there, change the source attribute of an image `document.getElementById().src = whatever you want to put here`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may want to use some javascript + css selectors for this.

First select your img element where you're changing the image:

```
let image = document.querySelector(".divClass img");
```

Or if you can set an id for image element that would be:

```
let image = document.getElementById("yourImgId");
```

Then check for the hostname with this:

```
let hostname = window.location.hostname;
```

And then use a regex to test domain names

```
if(/domain1.com/.test(hostname){
  image.src = yourImage1Url;
}
else if(/domain2.com/.test(hostname){
  image.src = yourImage2Url;
}
```

And so on you may do this further if someday there are more domains.

Edit: just to make sure everything happens when it's safe, you may wrap that code into a function and use it on an eventListener like this:

```
function YourFunctionName(){

  let image = document.getElementById("yourImgId");
  //or let image = document.getElementById("yourImgId");
  let hostname = window.location.hostname;
  if(/domain1.com/.test(hostname){
    image.src = yourImage1Url;
  }
  else if(/domain2.com/.test(hostname){
    image.src = yourImage2Url;
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", YourFunctionName);
```

I hope this helps you out.